# Why is this tiny pygame program freezing and doing nothing?

Tags: python, pygame

This program infinite loops. Does nothing. Won't take input or print anything. Ideas?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

running = 1
while(running):
   for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
         if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            print "hi"
            running = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your script is solely that there's no window that could capture the events.

You have to create and initialize a window with [`pygame.display.set_mode`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) first.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

# create a window that will capture the events
pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))

running = 1
while(running):
   for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
         if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            print "hi"
            running = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init(22050, -16, 2, 3072)
pygame.mixer.music.load("Kundara_Lake-of-Dust-320.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play(1, 0.0)

running = 1
while(running):
   for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
         if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
             pygame.mixer.music.stop()
             pygame.quit()
             running = 0
```

From http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html

> **pygame.quit**
>
> Uninitialize all pygame modules that have previously been initialized. When the Python interpreter shuts down, this method is called regardless, so your program should not need it, except when it wants to terminate its pygame resources and continue. It is safe to call this function more than once: repeated calls have no effect.
>
> Note, that pygame.quit will not exit your program. Consider letting your program end in the same way a normal python program will end.

You are looping infinitely calling `pygame.quit()` due to `while(1)`.

Comment: Unfortunately not the problem. I reduced the program to be just the while loop (with your "running" suggestion) and all that it does is print "hi" when you press Escape. But it still just does the infinite loop no results thing. Nothing happens until you end the program manually.

Comment: i think you need a window to capture input

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the screen. Try it with

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,32)
```

and in the loop, write

```
pygame.dispay.flip()
```

to close the window completely, you can use

```
sys.exit()
```

just be sure to include sys in your imports

Answer (score 0):

pygame does not recognize the term 'input' or 'print'. It would be a lot simpler if it did!! Instead, to get text onto the screen, you must use 'drawText('message',font,surface,(xpos,ypos) putting your own text in 'message', your own surface name in 'surface' and the x and y co-ordinates in 'xpos' and 'ypos'.